# Replace blank cells with 0 for specified range in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to replace the blanks cells in a specified range in each worksheet in a workbook with 0.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

With the code it works fine with the currently active worksheet, but does not cycle through the other worksheets.

```
Sub Zero()    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set r = Range("AB37:AQ52")
        For Each cell In r
            If cell.Value = "" Then cell.Value = 0
        Next cell
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it, you were not referencing each worksheet, just the one you had active, you need to use the `ws` to that:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub Zero()

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim r As Range

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            Set r = ws.Range("AB37:AQ52")
            r.Cells.Replace vbNullString, 0, LookAt:=xlWhole
        Next ws

    End Sub
```

Also, you don't need to loop the range, just use the  `Replace` function.

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks so much. The replace function is a lot faster than what I was doing before as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are blank you could alternatively use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceBlanksWithZeros()
    Dim BlankCells As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set BlankCells = Range("AB37:AQ52").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not BlankCells Is Nothing Then
        BlankCells.Value = 0
    End If
End Sub
```